# pgAdmin how to investigate traffic on the database server

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

Im using `pgAdmin 4` with `Postgres` database. My database is connected to the app. That app execute `SQL` queries on my database.

I want to look at queries that my app producing, what query was triggered on the database server.

Of course there is `Dashboard` panel on `pgAdmin` but it can cut some complex `SQLs` and if it dont, the SQL that Dashboard shows to me seems like not to work when i copy-pasted it to sql editor (to run it locally on the console).

My question is, how to track traffic on `Postgres` database? Im most intrested in the exact same queries as my app produce. No, i cant look into that queries into my app. Of course i can use another database ide as SSMS or DataGrip

Answer (score 1):

The parameter track_activity_query_size will limit the size of the text that can be retrieved from pg_stat_activity.query.  This will affect everyone who uses pg_stat_activity, not just PgAdmin4.

> SQL that Dashboard shows to me seems like not to work when i copy-pasted it to sql editor

What error do you get?

Comment: When i copy-pasted query from dashboard to any SQL developer client (im using DataGrip to execute queries) it says that something is missing like for example `from` statements or sql from Dashboard can be cutted in half in `Select ... ` and dont even come to `from` statement.

Comment: I can use any software to track activity on my database to be honest

Comment: Yes, by all means use what you like.  Personally I favor "psql" together with "auto_explain".  I sounds like your second problem is just a follow on to your first one, not a separate problem.  I thought you were saying it was a problem even when the query is *not* cut off.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that pgAdmin is the right tool to investigate queries run by an application. You could have a look to logging features like [log_statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/runtime-config-logging.html) and/or to extension [pg_stat_statements.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/pgstatstatements.html). These tools can give a lot of information on queries run in a database although they cannot filter for a specific application.